# Missing "Show a launcher when not running" option in KDE

Tags: 13.04, kubuntu, kde

After messing with Muon on Ubuntu 13.04 lots of installed packages suddently got removed, including most of the KDE packages. So I thought that installing `ubuntu-desktop` and `kubuntu-desktop` would restore most of them, at least the default ones, but it looks like someting is still missing because when I right-click an app icon at KDE panel I don't see an option to pin it to the panel, i.e. the "Show a launcher when not running" entry is missing.

Which package do I install to get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the Icon-only Task Manager and adding again solved the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detailes what is it you removed? I have the same problem and don't understand.